# Is it possible with Unity Mirror to make sure that each player has their own copy of the game world with their own progress?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I am new to game development. Now I'm trying to make a game similar in concept to Genshin Impact. And now I'm thinking about networking architecture.

In the mentioned game, the progress of the players is saved on the server, but each player has his own world. Those there is no common world where everyone sees each other, as in an MMO. But players can connect to each other's world and play together with up to 4 players in a team. At the same time, in multiplayer mode, players can be on different scenes.

So, I'm trying to implement just such an option. And I had a question, can I use Mirror for this or do I need to use something else? It seems that the concept is not too complicated, but I am a beginner and have only a superficial idea of ​​how to work with Mirror. But based on what I know about it so far, it's not clear to me how to do this and whether it is even possible. Therefore, I want to know if I should spend time studying the Mirror or look for other ways.